# problems launching slam_karto (ros-hydro)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I am getting problems trying to run the slam_karto package. First of all, the wiki page isn't updated for the karto slam. So I tried to look into the github for a possible ros hydro package. Found the one maintained by Mike Ferguson [slam_karto](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_karto).

Got the package into the catkin folder and build it with few errors about dependencies on g2o and SBA. Figured out from this repository [github link](https://github.com/sebasgm85/slam_karto/tree/groovy-devel). Everything build nicely with no errors.

I also found there is an apt-get package for slam_karto.

I run :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-slam-karto 

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-open-karto
```

Then, I sourced all the files properly from the /caktin_ws/devel/setup.bash and /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash

But when running `roslaunch slam_karto karto_slam.launch`

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [karto/slam_karto]: can't locate node [slam_karto] in package [karto]
```

Now, I am not sure where to look for this node? and how do I resolve this error and run the karto.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201827/problems-launching-slam_karto-(ros-hydro)/) by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 654 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks pretty much like the same problem as in your last question. When you install a package both from source and from apt-get, you should make sure that the correct one is used. (check with "roscd slam_karto") You probably have to remove the source packages from your ROS-Path when you want to use the apt-get-installed ones.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-01-27**:
roscd slam_karto gave me the following :~/catkin_ws/src/slam_karto/slam_karto

so in a way the path is correctly defined. (I removed the packages from the /opt/ros/hydro/share) and only have the sourced packages...

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-01-27**:
You probably have to execute: "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" once again after building for the first time.

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-01-28**:
i did sourced after running catkin_make. I am getting the same error.

what is the difference between ros node and ros driver?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2015-01-29**:
Check whether the node executables are available in /catkin_ws/devel/lib/. Else there might have been an error while building. Where did you read ros driver?